# From where to download xcode 5?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, mac, xcode

I am using xcode 4.6.3. and now i want to download xcode 5.

But i dont want to download it from itunes / mac store or apple developer site.

So what are the other sources to download the xcode 5 ?

Please provide me links for this..

Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason why you cannot download using MAS or the Apple Developer site? Are you using a Mac at all?

Comment: @MK yes i am using mac. And i have not configured itunes so i couldnt be able to download xcode. so i need other source to download it

Comment: Well, you have left out all legal ways of getting it in your question - you can get Xcode 5 only from MAS or from the Apple Developer site using a browser.

Comment: You don't need to 'configure iTunes' to download software or use the Mac App Store.

Comment: But he still needs an Apple Account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'configure iTunes' to download software or use the Mac App Store, but those are the official download channels.

If you really need to use a straight HTTP style download then you can get previous versions through being a registered developer https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode which might help, the most recent version available at the time of this post is V5 (September 18) which you can pull down in `.DMG` form.  Note that this is the free membership program, not the $99/year Mac Developer Program.

See more here https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: and i have another doubt that will this new xcode 5 will overwrite my previous version of my xcode (i.e 4.6.3)? what if i need both as separate?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 5 can be downloaded only from the Mac App Store or from the Apple Developer site.

You could create an [Apple ID](http://appleid.apple.com/) and use the Mac App Store to download it.

OR

- You could create a free developer account at the [Apple Developer portal](http://developer.apple.com/)
- go to the [downloads section](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)
- check only **Developer Tools** under Categories on the left (uncheck others, to make it simpler to find)
- then download the Xcode 5 DMG file.

Answer (score 0):

[XCode 5](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) can be downloaded from the Mac App Store for free. This of course requires an Apple ID but this can be set up in a few minutes in case you don't have one yet.